# Как выполняется оператор if на машинном уровне?

Tags: c++

как выполняется оператор условия(if) на машинном уровне.

Comment: насколько низкий уровень Вам интересен и сколько Вы знаете о ассемблере?

Comment: Обычно с помощью команд условного перехода...

Comment: тут почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602029/how-to-write-if-else-in-assembly

Comment: Засуньте код с `if`ом в дисассемблер и посмотрите на вывод...

Comment: Посмотрите пример с использованием cmp: http://asm-book.ru/faq/0049.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Код:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    if (x > 4) {
        printf("Larger");
    } else {
        printf("Smaller");
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Larger"
.LC1:
        .string "Smaller"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp

        // int x = 3;
        // mov – инструкция для перемещения значения
        movl    $3, -4(%rbp)

        // if (x > 4)
        // cmp – инструкция для сравнения значений
        cmpl    $4, -4(%rbp)
        // Если значение больше или равно, перейти к .L2
        jle     .L2

        // Иначе выполняется следующий код
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        // Перепрыгиваем блок else
        jmp     .L3

        // Блок else
.L2:
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf

        // Блок после if-else, окончание функции
.L3:
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [Онлайн Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org)
- [ВикиУчебник: Ассемблер для программистов C](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C)